# How to test if exception is thrown in AngularJS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-directive

I need to test a directive, and it should throw an exception. How can I test that the exception was thrown, in jasmine?

The directives link function:

```
link: function() {
    if(something) {
        throw new TypeError('Error message');
    }
}
```

I have not yet successfully implemented a test that actually catches the error and reports that the test was successful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
describe("myDirective", function() {
        it("should throw an error", inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
                function errorFunctionWrapper()
                {
                    $compile(angular.element("<div my-directive></div>"))($rootScope);
                }
                expect(errorFunctionWrapper).toThrow();
        }));
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    it("should throw an error", inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        expect(function () {
            $compile(angular.element("<directive-name></directive-name>"))($rootScope.$new());
        }).toThrow();
    }));
```

Comment: Using anonymous function is much more elegant solution IMO

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: this seems to be fixed now. Tested with Angular 1.6.4.

---

<s>In Angular 1.6, I'm been unable to catch errors thrown during the `$compile` phase. While not as elegant, I can still check against the `$exceptionHandler.errors` array ([source](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/23/ngmock-fundamentals-testing-exceptions/)):</s>

```
it('throws an error', function() {
  $compile(angular.element('<directive-name></directive-name>'))($rootScope.$new());
  expect($exceptionHandler.errors.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

<s>Better yet, provide it with the exact error message(s):</s>

```
expect($exceptionHandler.errors).toEqual(['first error', 'second error'])
```

Answer (score 0):

exception handling in angular testing is better done with native angular service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

this gives better handle on the thrown exceptions and provide a better native angular way to handle exception globally. say if at some point in time you can change the exception handling strategy of you application in a single place.

in testing this when used along with $exceptionHandlerProvider

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/provider/$exceptionHandlerProvider

gives you a better handle on the generated exception and write specific tests.

for unit tests it is not a standard way in angular to validate an exception using .toThrow(); method of jasmine.